# Getting class cast exception while returning Java bean from rhino script

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am getting 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject cannot be cast to my custom object`
 while type casting result of rhino script to java bean.

```
String scriptText = "importClass(com.UserBean);\nfunction getUser()\n{\nvar user = UserFactory.getInstance().getDefaultUser();\nreturn user;\n}"
UserBean user = (UserBean) executeScript(scriptText);
```

But while type casting i am getting class cast exception, Is there any thing i need to write in script to convert the native object to UserBean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got the answer, I need to convert native object to object and then type cast.

```
NativeJavaObject nativeObject = (NativeJavaObject) executeScript(scriptText);
UserBean user = (UserBean) nativeObject.unwrap();
```